# How to judge the day is next day via moment()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I use [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) to handle time in my code.

Here is a question:

I want to judge two times, if *now* is the next day of *last_take_time*

If I write like this:

```
   if not last_take_time? or (now.dayOfYear() - last_take_time.dayOfYear() is 1 )
      do_something()
```

There is a problem when last_take_time is the end day of a year.

I am newbie with JavaScript and Moment, but I think there is a right way to judge this.

Thanks!

Comment: I would do `if dateA - dateB is more than 25 hours OR dateA.date != dateB.date then are different days`.

Comment: @RobG no! 1) 2016-02-29:01:00:00  -  2016-02-28:23:00:00  only 2 hours, but they are different days; 2) I want to judge the next day, not different day!

Comment: If you want the next day, then `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)` works always. To compare, just zero the hours of both dates and compare time values.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `dayOfWeek()` then it is fairly easy to add an extra clause to test for the tricky case of Sunday / Monday:

```
if(last_take_time && (now.dayOfWeek() - last_take_time.dayOfWeek() == 1 
        || (now.dayOfWeek() == 1 && last_take_time.dayOfWeek() == 7)))
    do_something();
```

This is easier than dealing with the `dayOfYear()` because of having to deal with leap years.

**Edit**

Ah ok, I understand, you make a valid point - the answer above will return false positives when the days are more than a week apart. We can add a clause to account for this:

```
if(last_take_time && now.diff(last_take_time, 'days') < 3
        && (now.dayOfWeek() - last_take_time.dayOfWeek() == 1
        || (now.dayOfWeek() == 1 && last_take_time.dayOfWeek() == 7)))
    do_something();
```

The additional clause uses the `moment.js` method `diff()`: [link to docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to account for the highlighted issue.

Comment: sorry! it seems not right. considerring  last_take_time = 2016-02-01,  now = 2016-02-09 ,so now.dayOfWeek() is 2 and last_take_time.dayOfWeek() is 1

Answer (score 1):

If you have two dates and want to see if one is the next day after the other, 
just add one day to the "earlier" date, set the time to a common value (say zero) and test the time values, e.g.:

```js
// Return true if d1 is the day after d0
function isTomorrow(d0, d1) {
  d0 = new Date(+d0);
  d0.setDate(d0.getDate() + 1);
  return d0.setHours(0,0,0,0) == new Date(+d1).setHours(0,0,0,0);
}

document.write(
           isTomorrow(new Date(2016,1,28), new Date(2016,1,29)) // true
+ '<br>' + isTomorrow(new Date(2016,1,28), new Date(2016,2,1))  // false  
+ '<br>' + isTomorrow(new Date(2016,1,28,23,59), new Date(2016,1,29,0,1))  // true  
+ '<br>' + isTomorrow(new Date(2016,1,28,0,0), new Date(2016,1,29,23,59))  // true  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
if not last_take_time? or (now.startOf('day').add(1, 'day').isSame(last_take_time.startOf('day')) )
  do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a little simpler than the previous solutions:

What you want to know is the difference between now's day and another time's day.

Not: #24 hour periods between 2 times.

```
let now = moment();
let otherDay = moment("some other day");

let daysDiff = otherDay.startOf('day').diff(now, 'days');
if(daysDiff == 1) {
  // now is tomorrow relative to otherDay
}
```